# Retrain azure machine learning connected to SQL database

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I am trying to retrain the model connected to an Azure SQL database.  The sample code only deals with uploading CSV files.

It appears to post the data to a web service, make another call to pull back a job ID, then make a call to tell that job to start.  I assume the job is created when the CSV is updated, when I call that service directly skipping the first part, it's an empty array.  Calling the job start end point just gives me a 500 error with no jobID.  I basically think I need to tell it to refresh from the SQL server and then retrain but I cannot find any code related to that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this difficult to find in the documentation, but found this link that I was able to successfully run a batch execution without uploading a blob. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/web-services-that-use-import-export-modules

The key part is:

- Copy and paste the C# sample code into your Program.cs file, *and
  remove all references to the blob storage* (NOTE: you probably still want to have the blob storage for your output results, but not for uploading data)
- Locate the request declaration and update the values of Web Service
  Parameters that are passed to the Import Data and Export Data
  modules. In this case, you use the original query, but define a new
  table name.

To configure the Web Service Parameters for the import query and the destination table:

In the properties pane for the Import Data module, click the icon at the top right of the Database query field and select Set as web service parameter.
In the properties pane for the Export Data module, click the icon at the top right of the Data table name field and select Set as web service parameter.
At the bottom of the Export Data module properties pane, in the Web Service Parameters section, click Database query and rename it Query.
Click Data table name and rename it Table.

```
 var request = new BatchExecutionRequest() 
 {           
     GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
         { "Query", @"select [age], [workclass], [fnlwgt], [education], [education-num], [marital-status], [occupation], [relationship], [race], [sex], [capital-gain], [capital-loss], [hours-per-week], [native-country], [income] from dbo.censusdata" },
         { "Table", "dbo.ScoredTable2" },
     }
 };
```

Once you have the database as your load data module source, you need not have a web service input on the training module. You can also set a database query as a web parameter. Once you run the batch execution job to retrain the models, you can store them in Azure blob storage, and have your predictive model load them from there at runtime using "load trained model" modules rather than trained model modules. See this link for that procedure:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2017/06/19/loading-a-trained-model-dynamically-in-an-azure-ml-web-service/

So in short:

Use your SQL database as the source for your import data module

Run the batch execution process to retrain the model at whatever    interval you want

Save the retrained models (ilearner files) to blob storage, or at an http address that is accessable

Use the load trained model module in your predictive experiment rather than trained model.

put the path to your blob or url in the parameters of the load trained model module(s).

run, publish and test the predictive experiment with the dynamically loaded models

Note, this approach can be used if you have multiple models in your experiment.